# msal.js multi factor authentication screen not coming up

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, multi-factor-authentication, msal.js

I am using javascript based front-end application to call azure ad enabled functionapp functions. I have created ad app to access functionapp.I have used clientId , tenantId and scope created while registering the ad application in msal.js configuration.

```
 const myMSALObj = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
 myMSALObj.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
```

Whenever I am hitting the application url it redirects me to microsoft login screen and after entering credentials it gives below error message.
"Your sign-in was successful, but does not meet the criteria to access this resource"
It seems we have mfa enabled for ad users but while trying through above method I am not getting mfa screen. Any help would be really appreciated